# tfs visual studio error code 3 pre-build

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, tfs

When I download the code from FTS, and i build I have the following error

[image: error message]

when I delete the Pre-Build event command line the error disappears but I need the command line.

Any help please.

Comment: Share your Pre-Build event command line, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think the path is either incorrect or invalid. You can modify your pre-build from Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-Build Event.

Modify it and try again. It should work.

Comment: It work, but when I get the version of TFS error occurred.

Comment: Sorry. But I didn't get you.

Comment: What help? I did not understand.